# MSBuild for a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I hope this is a simple question. In Visual Studio 2010, I select the Debug or Release configuration, Any(CPU), click Build and my admittedly big and complicated solution builds like a champ.  When I go to a command prompt, change to my solution directory, run `path\msbuild.exe mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug` it craps out almost immediately.

I could tell you the specific error messages but asking you to read them would be too much to ask.

What I really am wondering about: what happens when I press F6 in VS2010? Does that not use MSBUILD?  Why can't I do the same thing with MSBUILD command line arguments or can I?  Should it not be simple since the sln file already exists?

Comment: That should work. Are you launching command from Visual Studio command prompt? If not, you have to execute %VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat before using msbuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/25/the-visual-studio-blog.aspx) has a bit of info on this and shows opening up the csproj file to see what F6 is doing.

You could do this for each project then incorporate these into a build script. [This blog](http://brennan.offwhite.net/blog/2006/11/29/msbuild-itemgroups-2of7/) has some good info on this.